# load non-local or external json/csv/data-files with d3.js / queue.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, queue.js

I have a problem regarding loading data files from an external server with d3, queue.js respectively. Basically what I want to do is to have my d3 graphs on multiple webservers, but the underlying data should be maintained centralized on a single webserver. So what I have in my code for the graphs is

```
  filenames_root = "http://www.myserver.com/data/";
  root_names = [ "1", "2", "3" ];

  var q = queue() 
              .defer(d3.json,filenames_root + "this_is_a.json");                    

  root_names.forEach( function (rn) { 
           q = q.defer(d3.csv,filename_root + rn + ".csv" ); 
      } );
  q.await(main);
```

However, when loading this code, the debugger halts indefinitely at

```
  q.await(main)
```

Any idea on how to overcome this problem is appreciated!

PS: I'm fairly new to JavaScript and web development, so please bear with me in case I made a beginner's mistake! I couldn't find anything regarding this problem on the web though.

Comment: The callback function. The snippet of code above works if I replace `filenames_root = "./"` and have local copies of the files.

Comment: Sounds like it can't connect to the server.

Comment: And how can I resolve that? The code above with `filenames_root = "http://www.myserver.com/data/` works well if I run it on www.myserver.com. Maybe there are some restrictions on myserver.com that prevent loading data externally?

Comment: Have you tried calling the URLs manually?